# How to write a line in a 'array' in a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I wrote a code in C# that get the user input and saves it in a JSON file, but like I need a database, that means that I'll need write several lines, but that's the problem, the code do not put it inside the []. Here is the output:

```json
[
    {"modelo":"gtr","ano":2004,"cor":"branco","marca":"nissan","placa":"123abc","completo":"sim","potencia":500},
    {"modelo":"gol","ano":2023,"cor":"preto","marca":"volkswagen","placa":"23b4ab","completo":"sim","potencia":130},
{"modelo":"enzo","ano":2015,"cor":"vermelho","marca":"ferrari","placa":"123456a","completo":"sim","potencia":700}


]
```

As you can see, the lines inside the [], I put manually, that one below is automatic by the code, I have to put that line inside the [].

```json
{"modelo":"292","ano":11,"cor":"11","marca":"292","placa":"1","completo":"11","potencia":1}
```

and here is the code:

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(estoque);

Console.WriteLine(jsonString);

string filePath = @"C:\Users\willi\Desktop\programas\CarDataBase\data.json";

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
 
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
 
    lines.Add(jsonString);
   // lines.Add();
    lines.Add("");
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

I have to put the lines(output) inside the [], as I explained above

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: I took the liberty of doing some basic cleanup, but it could still use some work. I suggest pasting the JSON into an IDE or online JSON validator and letting it format it for you, then copy and paste the result here.

Comment: What is `estoque`? If you want to serialize to an array, give `JsonSerializer.Serialize` an array/list/collection parameter.

Comment: To put @gunr2171's suggestion in other words, don't try and manipulate JSON manually; instead, manipulate the data structure, then serialize the data structure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your answer, don't use comments to show code.

Comment: I see, so i should serialize each data instead? like "cor", "modelo"?

Comment: Let me summarize this a little more, you want to read a json file, deserialize it into an object/list in c# and then serialize it back into json? Am I reading this correct?

Comment: Yes, want to put that output into an array

Answer (score 3):

But what is `JsonSerializer` created for? You should read your file, deserialize it into a C# `List<T>` of `Estoque` objects, add a new item to the list, serialize it, and rewrite your file.

*UPDATE*: here's an implementation.

```cs
string data = File.ReadAllText("YourFilePath"); // using System.IO

var array = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Estoque>>(data); // using System.Text.Json and using System.Collections.Generic

if (list == null) {
  // Error. Do something
  return;
}

list.Add(estoque); // Add your new object

string json = await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<List<Estoque>>(list);

File.WriteAllText("YourFilePath", json);
```

Comment: I think i got you, but i dont know actually how to do that, can you explain better how i do that, please? it would help me a lot, thanks

Comment: Added implementation, please have a look

Comment: in my code its showing some converting errors, like: "Cannot convert String to System.IO.Stream". Im already using all the libraries you comment in the code. Could be a librarie you forgot to comment?

Comment: Why do you deserialize to an array _then_ create a list, rather than deserializing directly to a list? That's awfully wasteful.

Comment: the part you are talking about is from microsoft serialization code example, i just copied that to my code and changed as i needed. Thanks for helping, i'll change the code and improve it.

Comment: @gunr2171 can it deserialize into a list? I didn't know. @elliot you can open a file stream and pass it to the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` method, instead of text from your JSON file.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json, code will be much simpler not only here but in the most cases in the future.

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    var arr = JArray.Parse(json);
    
    var newObj = JObject.FromObject(estoque);

    arr.Add(newObj);

    json = arr.ToString();

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
```

or more compact

```
    var arr = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    arr.Add(JObject.FromObject(estoque);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, arr.ToString());
```

Comment: i tried to use your code but it says the "newtonsoft" namespace does not exist, i have installed newtonsoft.json via terminal(nuget) already. Do i have to do something else?

Comment: @elliot did you type "using Newtonsoft.Json; "  at the top of your code?

Comment: yes, and i copied your code exacly and pasted, i just changed the "filepath", etc.

Comment: @elliot What .net and visual studio versions are you using?

Comment: yes, i did, thats the problem, the error message is about the "using newtonsoft", when i type "using NewtonSoft.Json", it says "type or  namaspace could not be found, are your missing a directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: dotnet 6.0 and vscode 1.73.1

Comment: @elliot   Do you have only one project in your solution?

Comment: yes, besides the program.cs, there's only the json file. Can u give me your discord, or something like that,  so we can talk better? i would appreciate.